I am getting (0 , _providers_SessionProvider__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.useSession) is not a function when trying to use a provider server side
I have created a Provider using jotai so I can save and load user's session in any page. The code below works fine when useSession is called in a client component but throws the error mentioned when called in an server side component. I have also tried using context from next.js/react but it also ended up throwing that it is not a function which means I am obviously doing something wrong but can't figure it out.
'use client';

import React, { useEffect, useState, Suspense } from "react";
import { useSetAtom } from "jotai";
import { sessionAtom, setSessionAtom, loadableSessionAtom} from "@/atoms/sessionAtom";
import { Provider, useAtomValue } from "jotai";
import Loader from "@/components/common/Loader";

export const useSession = () => {
    const sessionState = useAtomValue(loadableSessionAtom); // Read loadable session atom
    const setUser = useSetAtom(setSessionAtom); // Setter for session
    const user = useAtomValue(sessionAtom); // Current user state (reactive)
  
    return { sessionState, user, setUser };
};

export const SessionProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const setSession = useSetAtom(setSessionAtom);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Pre-fetch the session and update the state
        const fetchSession = async () => {
        const session = await loadableSessionAtom.read(); // Triggers fetch logic
        setSession(session);
        };
        fetchSession().catch(() => setSession(null));
    }, [setSession]);

    return <Provider>{children}</Provider>;
};

As the jotai documantation says I have wrapped the children elements with the provider in the root layout so it can be accessible in any component.
